# Relationship between optical coherence and spin dephasing?

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-spin, quantum-optics

I'm curious if there's a relationship between the inhomogeneous spin dephasing and the optical coherence of a material. Certainly, in many applications quantum information applications, you want both to be as long as possible. But, I'm curious if there is any direct relationship between the two?

More specifically, is there any direct relationship between the T<sub>2,spin</sub>* and the T<sub>2,optical</sub>*? Will increasing or decreasing one increase or decrease the other?